# Select option is not reflected properly while changing the option value dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an option box in html and I am trying to set the option using Angularjs. But its not working . Please find the code below.If I call the code in console and I am able to see the expected html is getting returned. Means , the changes are properly affected in the DOM but it is not getting reflected in UI.

**HTML**

```js
    angular.module('TestApp', []);
    var customers=false;
    var selectCustomer;
    var supplier=false;
    var selectSupplier;
    angular.module('TestApp').controller('CustomerController',
      function($scope, CustomerService) {
       $scope.callCustomer = function() {
        if(customers==false){
         console.log("i am in customer ajax call");
         customers=true;
         $scope.selected = [];
         CustomerService.getCustomers().then(function(serverdata) {
         selectCustomer=serverdata.data;
         $scope.selected=selectCustomer;
         }, function(error) {
         alert("data loading failed");
         console.log(error);
         });
        }else{
         console.log("selected customers are "+$scope.selected);
         $scope.selected=selectCustomer;
         console.log("selected customers are "+$scope.selected);
         console.log("I am out customer ajax call");
        }
        
       }
      });
    angular.module('TestApp').service(
      'CustomerService',
      function($http) {
       this.getCustomers = function() {
        return $http.get("http://" + document.location.host
          + "/SivaTask/getCustomer");
       }
      });
    // ====================================================================
    
    angular.module('TestApp').controller('SupplierController',
      function($scope, SupplierService) {
       $scope.callSupplier = function() {
        if(supplier==false){
          console.log("I am in supplier ajax call");
          $scope.selected = [];
          supplier=true;
          SupplierService.getSuppliers().then(function(serverdata) {
          selectSupplier=serverdata.data;
          $scope.selected=selectSupplier;
           
        }, function(error) {
         alert("data loading failed"); // user
         console.log(error);
        });
        }else{
         $scope.selected=selectSupplier;
         console.log("I am out supplier ajax call");
        }
       }
      });
    
    angular.module('TestApp').service(
      'SupplierService',
      function($http) {
       this.getSuppliers = function() {
        return $http.get("http://" + document.location.host
          + "/SivaTask/getSupplier");
       }
      });
    // ===================================================================
    
    function f1() {
     //alert("hello");
     console.log(document.getElementById("payterm").value);
     var value = document.getElementById("payterm").value;
     if (value == 'Payment') {
      var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("customerController")).scope();
      scope.callCustomer();
     } else if (value == 'Receipt') {
      var scope = angular.element(
        document.getElementById("supplierController")).scope();
      scope.callSupplier();
     } else {
      alert("invalid selection");
     }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
   <th>
   <td><select id="payterm" ng-model="payterm">
     <option value="Payment" onclick="f1()">Payment</option>
     <option value="Receipt" onclick="f1()">Receipt</option>
   </select></td>


   <td><select id="payment" ng-model="payment">
     <option value="Cash" onclick="f1()">Cash</option>
     <option value="Bank" onclick="f1()">Bank</option>
   </select></td>

   <td>
    <div id="customerController" ng-controller="CustomerController">
     <div id="supplierController" ng-controller="SupplierController">
      <select id="select" ng-model="select">
                    <option ng-repeat="select in selected">{{select}}</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </td>

   <td><input id="amount" type="text" ng-model="amount" /></td>
   <td>
    <button name="add" ng-controller="ConcatController"
     ng-click="concat();">+</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-click` instead of `onclick` for AngularJS:

```
   <td><select id="payterm" ng-model="payterm">
            <option value="Payment" ng-click="f1()">Payment</option>
            <option value="Receipt" ng-click="f1()">Receipt</option>
    </select></td>
```

Besides that, for `ng-model="payterm"` you should use:

```
$scope.payterm
```

to do the two way binding.

Comment: Still i am facing same issue.Proper data is showing on console.But in UI is not reflected.For the first time when user selected "Payment" then automatically payment details are showing.But if the user select other option say "Receipt" and again select payment only Receipt details are showing on ui. Payment details are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to use here is the `ng-change` directive

**HTML**

```
<td><select ng-controller="SelectCtrl" id="payterm" ng-model="payterm" ng-change="someFunc()">
        <option value="Payment">Payment</option>
        <option value="Receipt"">Receipt</option>
</select></td>
```

**JS**

```
angular.controller('SelectCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.payterm = ""; 
    $scope.someFunc = function() {
      // do something
      console.log($scope.payterm);
    };
]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the f1 method is running outside of the angular scope.
Angular has no idea what is happening when f1 is running and thats why the gui is not behaving correctly.

But, the main question to your solution is why does f1 exist? 
If you are only interesting in a method to determind which options that is selected on the payterms and payments you can do this, 
which is also recommended, in pure angularjs.

Here's an example

```js
angular.module('TestApp', []);
angular.module('TestApp').controller('PaymentController', function($scope) {
 $scope.payterms = [{name: 'Payment'}, {name: 'Receipt'}];
 $scope.payments = [{name: 'Cash'}, {name: 'Bank'}];
});
angular.module('TestApp').controller('CustomerController',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'customer1'}, 
            {name: 'customer2'}];
});
angular.module('TestApp').controller('SupplierController',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.suppliers = [
            {name: 'supplier1'}, 
            {name: 'supplier2'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="PaymentController">

<select ng-model="payterm" ng-options="item.name for item in payterms">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
 </select>
<select ng-model="payment" ng-options="item as item.name for item in payments">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
 </select>
  
 <div ng-show="payment" ng-controller="CustomerController">
 Customers
 <select ng-model="customer" ng-options="item as item.name for item in customers">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div ng-show="payterm" ng-controller="SupplierController">
 Suppliers
 <select ng-model="supplier" ng-options="item as item.name for item in suppliers">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
       </select>
 </div>

</div>
```